# Ansible fail "skipping: no hosts matched" with ansible-pull

Tags: ansible

I try to use ansible-pull and synchronize module to sync files from a remote server to the local server.  I use ansible-pull it failed and shows 'skipping: no hosts matched' but when I copy the playbook file to my local server and run as ansible-playbook, it works.

my hosts setting

```
localhost ansible_connection=local

[sync_server]
sync_1 ansible_host=11.22.33.44
```

playbook file

```
---
 - name: Sync Test
    hosts: sync_server
    tasks:

      - name: Start Sync
        synchronize:
          mode: pull
          src: /home/sourcefiles
          dest: /home/syncfiles/
```

- ansible version 2.5.1
- python version 2.7.17
- Sync server and client os ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Welcome to SO! See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Include at least the `ansible-pull` command and the output.

Answer (score 0):

Without a little bit more detail (notably, the command you're actually executing, or at least a lightly modified version without your real VCS repository), it looks like you might not be invoking your playbook with a hosts/inventory file specified OR your inventory might not be parsed properly.

You can run `ansible-inventory --graph` to see a list of the hosts which have been "detected" with this inventory. You should also check `ansible-config dump | grep DEFAULT_HOST_LIST` to see whether you're specifying the path to your inventory.

If this *is* where the issue lies, then you should try one of the following:

1. Configure an ansible.cfg with (at least) the following lines:

```
[defaults]
inventory = hosts
```

2. Try `ansible-pull` using the switch `--inventory` (which can be shortened to `-i`) followed by path to your inventory file, like this: `ansible-pull --inventory hosts --url http://example.org/my/vcs.git playbook.yml`